# Use method of model class within save method

Tags: django, django-models

I'm trying to override the save method of one of my models.  Within that save method I would like to use another method of the model, like this:

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)

    def do_something(self):
        pass

    def save(self,*args, **kwargs):
        self.do_something()
        super(MyModel, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

This doesn't work because when django executes the save, the object is a generic ModelBase class and not my subclass of ModeBase.  So I get:

```
unbound method do_something() must be called with MyModel instance as first argument (got ModelBase instance instead)
```

What is the right way to do this?

Comment: Can you call the method `super(MyModel, self).save(*args, **kwargs)` before you call `self.do_something()`? So just switch the two so that the object will get created first.

Comment: I have tried that--it doesn't seem to help.  Also, I'd like to make sure the 'do_something' completes successfully before I save the model.

Answer (score 1):

You should put `args` and `kwargs` to overridden `save()`method too:

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)

    def do_something(self):
        pass

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.do_something()
        super(MyModel, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

You also forgot `self` parameter in `do_something()`!

**UPDATE**

I don't quite understand your problem. If you want to call unbound method `do_something`, define it outside the class `MyModel` with one and just call it from `save()` like `do_something(self):

```
class MyModel(class.Model):
  def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    do_something(self)
    super(MyModel, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

def do_someting(my_model_instance):
  assert isinstance(my_model_instance, MyModel)
  ...
```

Comment: Thanks.  Should be good now.  It's hard debugging made up code!

Comment: Welcome. If that answer solved your problem, consider clicking checkmark to mark this answer Accepted.

Comment: That really doesn't solve the actual problem. We'll see what else comes in.

Comment: That's what I'd like to avoid really.  Obviously I can take all my methods outside the model.